# Prometheus operator warnings "Too old resource version "

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I want to understand what is this resources which is causing error? That can help to understand what triggered this

Prometheus:
quay.io/coreos/prometheus-operator: 0.38.1
quay.io/prometheus/prometheus: 2.18.2

````
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:23:33.759Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77932793 (77933474)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:24:34.683Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77931607 (77933976)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:25:59.216Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77932221 (77934666)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:27:51.400Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77932973 (77935587)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:29:18.452Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77932955 (77936328)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:31:02.169Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77933801 (77937181)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:35:37.222Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77938858 (77939462)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:40:00.769Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77937615 (77941622)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:41:24.693Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77938126 (77942327)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:41:33.409Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77939775 (77942403)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:42:57.461Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77940485 (77943069)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:46:45.177Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77941349 (77944970)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:51:07.231Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77943616 (77947157)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:51:31.469Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77947266 (77947349)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:53:23.418Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77946542 (77948276)"
level=warn ts=2020-09-01T09:53:30.779Z caller=klog.go:86 component=k8s_client_runtime func=Warningf msg="/app/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:361: watch of *v1.Endpoints ended with: too old resource version: 77945788 (77948343)" ```
````

Comment: First google result: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/2730

Comment: Yes but did you also read https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22024 ? Its not an issue unless multiple times per second. I am seeing it multiple times per second. Hence created a post here

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this as a community wiki answer for better visibility.

> I want to understand what is this resources which is causing error?

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22024#issuecomment-591814814) by @antoineco

> When nothing happens in your cluster, the watches established by the Kubernetes client don't get a chance to get refreshed naturally, and eventually time out. These messages simply indicate that these watches are being re-created.

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/2730#issuecomment-524342055) by @squat.

> This is a known occurrence in Kubernetes and is not an issue. The API server ends watch requests when they are very old. The operator uses a client-go informer, which takes care of automatically re-listing the resource and then restarting the watch from the latest resource version.

---

> I am seeing it multiple times per second

From the logs you provided I wouldn't say it's multiple times per second, it's only several per hour, if you're worried it's too much I would suggest to ask about that on [prometheus-operator github](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues).